# Unable to create object from form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

After changing the field used as the primary key in a model, I now receive an error when trying to create an object from a form.

I have deleted the sqlite database file, everything in the migrations directory, and performed makemigrations and migrate. I do not believe the problem is with the database, rather something in the code no longer functions the same now that I am not using a custom primary key.

As someone new to Django, I suspect I am missing something fundamental but cannot quite identify what that is.

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def job_create(request):
    client = request.POST.get('client')
    form = JobForm(request.POST or None)
    form.fields['client'].initial = Client.objects.get(client_name=client)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return JsonResponse({"Success": True})`
```

**models.py**

```
class Client(models.Model):
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.client_name

class Job(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job_number = models.CharField(validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^\d{4}$', message='Invalid job number', code='invalid')], max_length=4, unique=True)
    job_description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

**forms.py**

```
class JobForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ('client', 'job_number', 'job_description',)`
```

The above code fails to create and save the object into the database. Below is my attempt to recreate this using the Django shell:

```
>>> from myproject.models import Client, Job
>>> from myproject.forms import JobForm
>>> client = Client.objects.get(client_name='John')
>>> jobform = JobForm({'client': client, 'job_description':'This is a job description', 'job_number':'4321'})
>>> jobform.errors
{'client': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}
```

**Database Columns**

```
sqlite> PRAGMA table_info(myproject_job);
0|id|integer|1||1
1|job_number|varchar(4)|1||0
2|job_description|varchar(30)|1||0
3|client_id|integer|0||0
```

**Solution for now**

```
@login_required
def job_create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        client = Client.objects.get(client_name=request.POST.get("client"))
        request.POST = request.POST.copy()
        request.POST["client"] = client.id
        form = JobForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return JsonResponse({"success": "true"})
```

Comment: Could you please edit your post and add the output of `jobform.errors`. This will show you and us what is wrong.

Comment: What error are you getting? Note, your test does not replicate what the form does; you need to pass a dictionary to the instantiation of JobForm.

Comment: Updated to reflect this.

Comment: Was it the `Client` model where you changed the primary key?

Comment: It was, but I also changed the primary key on the Job model as well. Basically, the primary key for the Client model was the client_name field; and the primary key for the Job model was the job_number field. I then realised that this wasn't a good idea as I may need to edit those fields, so I wanted to revert to the default auto id.

Comment: I suspect what has happened is that after you changed the primary key and ran `python manage.py migrate`, Django migrated the primary key fields, but left the foreign key field in `Job` still referencing the `CharField` in `Client`. If you look at the `client_id` column in the `job` table, what does it contain - names or ids?

Comment: But wouldn't deleting the sqlite database and running makemigrations and migrate have resolved that issue?


sqlite> select client_id from myproject_job;

4

Comment: Edited my question to include the fact that I had deleted the sqlite database prior to makemigrations/migrate. Also provided database columns.

Comment: OK... so it appears that when creating the form I need to pass client.id rather than client -- is this expected behavior?

Comment: I am still unable to create the object via the form method. Even if I provide an initial value of client.id for the 'client' field when instantiating the form, it still does not work.

Comment: I am starting to wonder whether this might be a bug with the version of Django I am using (2.1.5). The release notes suggest that several bugs were fixed relating to SQLite... perhaps something else was broken in the process?

Comment: Downgraded to Django version 2.1, deleted database file, ran migrations... still no luck. What am I missing here?

Comment: Added my "solution" for now... though would like to understand why my method isn't valid.